# Perfect square of $n$ primes in $2^n$ row

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4$ be prime numbers. The state is:we can't put them in row $p_{i_1}, p_{i_2}, \ldots, p_{i_{16}}$, $p_{i_j} \in \{p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4 \}$ so that $$ \prod_{j = m}^{n} p_{i_j} \not = q^2$$ for $1 \leq m < n \leq 16 $, $q \in \mathbb{N}?$ Is there any good invariant proof? It seems that this fact is true even for $n$ primes and $2^n$ lenght row.

Comment: Wait can you demonstrate with an example? Perhaps my english is tripping. Also you didn't state any fact, you asked a question :)

Comment: For example if there is 4 $p_j$ for $1 \leq j \leq 4$ the product is $(p_1 p_2 p_3 p_4) ^4$ = perfect square, the state is that there exists a subrow in row lenght 16 such that his product is perfect square

Comment: Can I rephrase as following: I have 16 blank spaces `_ _ _ ... _ _`. Fill in each with one of the four prime numbers given $\{p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4\}$ such that no contiguous subinterval's product is a perfect square.

Comment: I have no idea what the question is.  Are you using "state" as a synonym for "statement"?  Are the primes distinct?   Suppose the primes are $\{3,5,7,11\}$.  What exactly are you asking in that case?

Comment: @lulu I think, I figured it out after having read the question about 3 times. If we write down $3,5,7,11$ each 4 times in any order, there is a block with length smaller than $16$ such that each prime occurs an even number of times (so the product of this block is a perfect square)

Comment: @Peter  Ah, yes.  That makes sense.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming my rephrase in the comments is correct. If not, I will delete this answer.

I am not sure how to directly write the proof in math notation, so I will give a short example. let the primes be $2, 3, 5, 7$ and the row be

$$2, 5, 3, 3, 5, 2, 7, 7, 3, 7, 5, 2, 3, 5, 2, 7$$

We have that the product of term 2 to 5 is $5\cdot 3\cdot3\cdot 5=15^2$, as well as many other intervals (9 to 16 for example)

---

Let's rewrite the primes as four vectors - $(1, 0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1, 0)$ and $(0, 0, 0, 1)$. Then the **multiplication/product** operation
can be replaced by an **addition** operation under $\mod 2$ ($\mathbb{Z}_2$). Moreover, the requirement of $\prod_{i=s}^e r_i \neq q^2$ can be rephrased as $\sum_{i=s}^e r_i \neq \vec{0}$. For example, term 2 to 5's sum is $$\underbrace{(0,0,1,0)}_5+\underbrace{(0,1,0,0)}_3+\underbrace{(0,1,0,0)}_3+\underbrace{(0,0,1,0)}_5=(0,0,0,0)\mod 2$$

The next step is to rewrite the sum into the difference of **prefix sum**. This is done like this:

$$\sum_{i=s}^e r_i=\sum_{i=1}^e r_i - \sum_{i=1}^{s-1} r_i$$

The requirement $\sum_{i=s}^e r_i\neq \vec{0}$ can again be rephrased as $$\sum_{i=1}^e r_i \neq \sum_{i=1}^{s-1} r_i$$

Notice that both of the terms are in the form of $\sum_{i=1}^{x} r_i$, where $0\leq x\leq 16$.

Finally, the sum is a vector of length 4 with each element in $\{0, 1\}$, so there is at most $2^4=16$ choices of $\sum_{i=1}^{x} r_i$.

Since there are essentially $17$ terms with $0\leq x\leq 16$, by pigeonhole principle there must be two prefix-sums that are the same, or equivalent that in the original question, there exists a subinterval for which its product is a perfect square.

---

Again, sorry for the bad english, but if you don't understand feel free to ask and I will add on to my current answer.

Gareth

Comment: Also note that the vector is essentially the exponents of the prime factorisation, so like $2^i\cdot 3^j\cdot 5^k\cdot 7^l \to (i,j,k,l)$

Comment: Nice +1 .........

Comment: @Aqua Thanks! great that ppl actually understand >.<

Answer (score 3):

$\prod_{j = 1}^{n} p_{i_j} $ will have odd power of one or more prime for $1\le n\le16$ otherwise we are done.
Among 4 primes number of ways you can have odd power of one or more prime$=2^4-1=15$. Example of one of the ways will be $p_1,p_2$ having odd powers in the product, another example would be $p_2,p_3,p_4$ having odd powers in the product.

Then by pigeon  hole principal there exists $a> b$ such that $
\prod_{j = 1}^{a} p_{i_j}$ and $\prod_{j = 1}^{b} p_{i_j}$ have same primes with odd power.
Then $\frac{\prod_{j = 1}^{a} p_{i_j} }{\prod_{j = 1}^{b} p_{i_j} }=\prod_{j = b-1}^{a} p_{i_j} $ will be a square.